# trying to make the code using javascript call to work

Tags: jquery

Unfortunately this code below does not print anything on the firebug console, neither does it throw an error, not sure what is wrong with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var animals = [  
      {species: 'Lion', name: 'King'},  
      {species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail'}  
    ];  

    for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {  
      (function (i) {   
        this.print = function () {   
          console.log('#' + i  + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name);   
        }   
      }).call(animals[i], i);  
    }  

});
```

Comment: You're not calling `this.print()` at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a `.print()` method to each object in the `animals` array, but you are never calling that method so there is no expected output from this code.